# How recover data from a RadioGroup in another activity?

Tags: android, radio-group, data-recovery

I need to recover the option that the user chose and pass it to another activity, how can I do it?

```
public class SelectServicesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn_seleccion;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
TextView tvServicio1, tvServicio2, tvServicio3;
RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_services);

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg_servicios);
    btn_seleccion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_seleccion);
    rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb1);
    rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb2);
    rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb3);


btn_seleccion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1)
            {
                // no radio buttons are checked
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Por favor, selecciona una opción", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                // one of the radio buttons is checked
                Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), SelectDayActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }

             }

    });


     }}
```

The option that the user chooses must be retrieved in another activity.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), SelectDayActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("value", valueToSend);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Then in Second activity get it `onCreate()`

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but u can add the following line on button click

```
int selectedId = radioGroup .getCheckedRadioButtonId();
if(selectedId == -1) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Por favor, selecciona una opción", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}

RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
String selected_option = radioButton.getText().toString().trim();
Intent intent = new Intent (SelectServicesActivity , SelectDayActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("SELECTED_ITEM", selected_option);
intent.putExtra("SELECTED_BUNDLE", bundle);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

now on receiving end (SelectDayActivity.class) inside onCreate() retrieve the selected_option like this

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("SELECTED_BUNDLE");
String value = bundle.getString("SELECTED_ITEM");
Log.e("TAG", "_log : value : " + value); // should print your option
```

Comment: I think that I need to declare a string variable, what do you think?

Comment: You don't need to declare a String variable on SelectServicesActivity.class. but on SelectDayActivity.class, You can declare String selected_option globally.

Comment: I compiled my code but in the second activity the selected item is not displayed

Comment: print a Log/Toast to check what is the value selected_option hold. kindly check this

Comment: @Odalis T : I'm just verifying my code & its works perfectly. If You have a RadioGroup (where there is 3 Radio Buttons with options [for example] Yes, No, May Be). and if You choose either one of them (lets say, May Be) & then click the button, it'll go on next Activity where I retrieve the data & print that data (it show May Be).

Comment: When I choose an option and press the button, I can validate with Toast the value selected_option, but in the second activity is not shown

Comment: how  do u receive that selected_option on your Second Activity? kindly paste your code here

Comment: Now the application does not work, it stops after clicking on the activity "SelectServicesActivity"

Answer (score 0):

I modified this part and added a Toast to validate the selected option:

```
int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) radioGroup.findViewById(selectedId);

            if(selectedId == -1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Por favor, selecciona una opción", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            Toast.makeText(SelectServicesActivity.this, "servicio " + rb.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            String selected_option = rb.getText().toString().trim();
            Intent intent = new Intent (SelectServicesActivity.this, SelectDayActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("SELECTED_ITEM", selected_option);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);


             }
```

In the other activity where I want to receive the information, I added this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_verificar_datos);

    textView_tipo_servicio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_tipo_servicio);
    String selected_option = getIntent().getStringExtra("SELECTED_ITEM");
    textView_tipo_servicio.setText(selected_option);
```

The problem is that the information is not displayed.

Comment: @msh.nayan look

Comment: on SelectServicesActivity.class Toast is showing proper option ?

Comment: I've updated my answer above (first answer of mine). kindly check